# Starvation Free Mutex In Little Book of Semaphores

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, mutex, semaphore

## Background:

The Little Book of Semaphores by Allen B. Downey talks about assumptions needed to prevent thread starvation.

He states that the scheduler needs to guarantee the following:

> Property 2: if a thread is ready to run, then the time it waits until it runs is bounded.

And a **weak semaphore** guarantees:

> Property 3: if there are threads waiting on a semaphore when a thread executes signal, then one of the waiting threads has to be woken.

However, he states that even with these properties, the following code when run for 3 or more threads (Thread A,B,C) can cause starvation:

```
while True: 
    mutex.wait()
    # critical section 
    mutex.signal()
```

The argument is that if A executes first, then wakes up B, A could wait on the mutex again before B releases it. At this point, the A could be woken up again reacquire the mutex and repeat this cycle with B. C would be starved.

## Question:

Wouldn't Property 2 guarantee that C would have to be woken up by the scheduler in some finite amount of time? If so, then Thread C couldn't be starved. Even if **weak semaphore** does not guarantee that Thread C will be woken up, shouldn't the scheduler run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about it a little bit more and realized that **Property 2** is guarantees that Threads in a RUNNABLE state will be scheduled in a finite amount of time.

The argument in the book states that Thread C would never get to a RUNNABLE state so Property 2 and 3 do not guarantee no starvation.